# Identify the incorrect history handled records

Tags: teradata

I have some data in a table where the history got incorrectly handled because of **blanks/spaces** coming in one column segment_value_cd.

I have to identify such records from the table.

I tried few queries but it;s fetching me the entire results.

Is there any way to identify only such records?

```
Sel * from party_segment where party_id in(6303031,6824664,216502393,6916270)
    id  Segment_Type_Cd Segment_Value_Cd    Segment_Start_Dt    Segment_End_Dt
    6,303,031   MB                             3/20/2013           6/7/2015
    6,303,031   MB         ?                    6/7/2015            ?
    6,824,664   MB                             3/20/2013           6/7/2015
    6,824,664   MB          ?                     6/7/2015          ?
    6,916,270   MB         ?                      9/28/2015         ?
    6,916,270   MB                             3/20/2013        9/28/2015
    216,502,393 NR        ?                       6/7/2015             ?
    216,502,393 NR                           8/7/2010          6/7/2015
```

Thanks for your help!!

EDIT:

The query is also fetching this party. However here history got handled because the segment_type_cd got changed.

```
23,707  KA          7/11/2010   3/6/2011    
23,707  NM          3/6/2011    6/29/2011   
23,707  KA          6/29/2011   3/25/2014   
23,707  MB          3/25/2014   5/29/2014   
23,707  KA          5/29/2014   6/7/2015    
23,707  MB  LC      6/7/2015    9/28/2015   
23,707  KA  ?       9/28/2015         ?
```

My requirement is to fetch only those parties where the segment_type_cd remains same and the history got handled based on blank and null segment_value_cd 
and then merge those two records into one. Like the one below. I have to identify these and merge into one.

```
1   6,824,664   MB          3/20/2013   6/7/2015    
2   6,824,664   MB  ?        6/7/2015   ?
```

Comment: There are NULLs and empty strings? And what exactly are you trying to return? IDs where both exist?

Comment: `where col = ''` will get empty strings (white space, not null).  `where col is null` will get nulls.  `where (col is null or col = '')` will get you both.

Comment: @dnoeth: I have to correct the history where these are occuring and merge those two records into one. Yes the history got created because a trim was missing in the code and blank/spaces was coming into segment value column.

Comment: @Andrew: yes but its also give results where history was handled like below:
25,790 MB SS     7/11/2010 2/26/2014
25,790 GI        2/26/2014 6/7/2015
25,790 MB        6/7/2015 8/4/2015
25,790 GH        8/4/2015 8/23/2015
25,790 KA        8/23/2015 10/6/2015
25,790 GH ? 10/6/2015 ?

Comment: My requirement is to correct history only where the history was handled because of the change in segment value from space to Null and the segment type remain same.
There are scenarios where the history got handled because of change in type_cd and the segment values are only spaces. I don't have to correct that.

Comment: @dnoeth, Yes ids were both exist in consecutive records and got history handled

Comment: To check if both NULL and space exist for the same party/type: `qualify min(Segment_Value_Cd) over (partition by party_id, Segment_Type_Cd) = '' and count(Segment_Value_Cd) over (partition by party_id, Segment_Type_Cd) <>  count(*) over (partition by party_id, Segment_Type_Cd)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Dnoeth!! Let me try.

Comment: Hi @dnoeth,
Thanks for your response.
With the above i am able to identify all the party whose history got handled because of type_cd as well . Please check the EDIt part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return any two consecutive rows with an empty string and a NULL in arbitrary order:

```
qualify -- within two rows there's both
        -- an empty string
   max(Segment_Value_Cd)
   over (partition by party_id, Segment_Type_Cd
         order by Segment_Start_Dt
         rows 1 preceding) = '' 
and      -- and a NULL
   min(case when Segment_Value_Cd is null then '*' end)
   over (partition by party_id, Segment_Type_Cd
         order by Segment_Start_Dt
         rows 1 preceding) is not null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dnoeth!! That's perfect! I wanted to merge those two records into one without changing the other history, but it's getting a bit complicated.